# Sum using the last two elements of a dictionary's tupled key

Tags: python, sum

I have lists

```
A = [(i,j,k,l,m)]
B = [(l,m,k)]
```

and dictionaries

```
C = {(i,j,k,l,m): val}
D = {(l,m,k): other_val}
```

I would like to create a dictionary of `E` such that

```
E = {(i,j,k): C[(i,j,k,l,m)]*D[(l,m,k)]}
```

Assume that all indexing convention matches in the lists and dictionaries. I have the below non-Pythonic, extremely slow solution. Is there any Pythonic way to quickly do this for very large `A` sizes, e.g., 5 million rows?

```
E = {}
for i,j,k,l,m in A:
    E[i,j,k] = sum(
        C[i,j,k,l,m] * D[l2,m2,k2] 
        for l2,m2,k2 in B if l2==l and m2==m and k2==k)
```

Below is the code to generate a sample dataset that is near the actual size trying to be dealt with.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

Irange = range(50)
Jrange = range(10)
Krange = range(80)
Lrange = range(8)
Mrange = range(18)

A = [
    (i,j,k,l,m)
    for i in Irange
    for j in Jrange
    for k in Krange
    for l in Lrange
    for m in Mrange]
B = [
    (l,m,k)
    for k in Krange
    for l in Lrange
    for m in Mrange]

C = {key: np.random.uniform(1,10) for key in A}

D = {key: np.random.uniform(0,1) for key in B}

E = {}
for i,j,k,l,m in A:
    E[i,j,k] = sum(
        C[i,j,k,l,m] * D[l2,m2,k2]
        for l2,m2,k2 in B if l2==l and m2==m and k2==k)
```

Comment: I think the best is to transform this into a numpy problem

Comment: Yes, using numpy arrays here will be much more efficient.

Comment: Are tuples in `B` unique?

Comment: But I think you can filter out the inner loop

Comment: Yes, `A` and `B` include unique tuples. They are formed like `list(set())...`

Comment: Do something like `lookup_B = { key : D[key] for key in B}` and then `sum(C[i,j,k,l,m]*lookup_B[(l, m, k)])` this makes the inner part `O(1)` instead of `O(n)`

Comment: Please add some sample data so we can test our answers

Comment: @DaniMesejo Added code to generate sample data.

Comment: B is formed like `list(set())`? Why turn the useful set into an inappropriate list?

Comment: I tried running it, but after a minute it didn't produce any output. Could you provide a smaller dataset please?

Comment: For a smaller dataset, please consider reducing numbers in the ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting my fast enough solution. If you still see an improvement possibility, I am happy to test it out. (I was expecting some libraries to already have a faster solution; maybe, there is, but my question/solution approach was not clear enough to utilize one).

Here is the data generation code:

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
np.random.seed(1)

Irange = range(50)
Jrange = range(10)
Krange = range(80)
Lrange = range(8)
Mrange = range(18)

A = [
    (i,j,k,l,m)
    for i in Irange
    for j in Jrange
    for k in Krange
    for l in Lrange
    for m in Mrange]
B = [
    (l,m,k)
    for k in Krange
    for l in Lrange
    for m in Mrange]

C = {key: np.random.uniform(1,10) for key in A}

D = {key: np.random.uniform(0,1) for key in B}
```

First, start timer and introduce a list `unique_ijk`:

```
start_timer = datetime.now() #Start counting time
unique_ijk = list(set([(i,j,k) for i,j,k,l,m in A]))
```

Then, create a dictionary called `lm_given_ijk` that is valued with a list of l,m indices corresponding to a given i,j,k tuple key.

```
lm_given_ijk = {(i,j,k):[] for i,j,k in unique_ijk}
for i,j,k,l,m in A:
    lm_given_ijk[i,j,k].append((l,m))
```

Finally, use `lm_given_ijk` as follows to create `E`.

```
E = {(i,j,k): sum(C[i,j,k,l,m]*D[l,m,k] for l,m in lm_given_ijk[i,j,k]) 
                  for i,j,k in unique_ijk}
print("Elapsed time is %s seconds.\n"%(datetime.now()-start_timer).total_seconds())
```

Output:

```
Elapsed time is 6.446798 seconds.
```

Writing all these, I agree with comments saying this is a numpy array thing. It could improve the speed, but I am happy with 6.4 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict

b = set(B)  # O(#B)
E = defaultdict(float)
for i,j,k,l,m in A: # O(#A)
    if (l, m, k) in b:
        E[i,j,k] += C[i,j,k,l,m] * D[l, m, k]
```

This approach has `O(#A + #B)` complexity.
The naive implementation, leaving correctness issues aside, is `O(#A * #B)`.

Comment: Computes something different, as you changed their `=` to `+=`.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode exactly. This is the "leaving correctness issues aside" part

Comment: Hmm, then why not simply replace the entire code with `pass` and say "O(1), leaving correctness aside"? :-)

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode let the OP decide if it was a correct assumption

Answer (score -1):

`D` has the same keys as `B`, so why are you iterating over `B` and summing one element? You can just get `D[l,m,k]` directly.

```
E[i,j,k] = C[i,j,k,l,m] * D[l,m,k]
```

Converted to dict comprehension:

```
E = {(i,j,k): C[i,j,k,l,m]*D[l,m,k] for i,j,k,l,m in A}
```

On my computer, this gave about a 150x speed up (15s → 0.086s), though for practicality, I halved all your input dimensions since your original code went for more than a minute without producing any output.

Comment: Btw their code (and thus also yours) doesn't make sense. They overwrite the same `E[i,j,k]` many times. I'm guessing they don't actually want to overwrite but *do* want to add somehow.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Oh yeah, since there are multiple elements in `A` with the same `i,j,k` -- `l*m` elements to be exact. Huh